# How to extract an object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, extract

I have this code, where a username is required from a fake db:

```
const MY_FAKE_DB = require('./my_db.js')  

const username = 'jdoe2'; 
const user = MY_FAKE_DB.users[username]; 
console.log(user.name, user.passwordHash)
```

And the "dataBase" (my_db.js) is the next one:

```
    const users =
{
    jdoe2: [{
        username: "jdoe2",
        name: "Jhoe",
        passwordHash: "1234"
    }],

    lmart: [{
        username: "lmart",
        name: "Luis",
        passwordHash: "2345"
    }]
}
```

I don´t know how to get from users the user whose username is jdoe2.

Thanks for the help

Comment: "I don´t know how to get from users the user whose username is jdoe2" By writing code, that's how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things that are causing problems here.

First to use `require`, you should `export` your object from the fake db. Something like:

```
// my_db.js
const users = {
    jdoe2: {
        username: "jdoe2",
        name: "Jhoe",
        passwordHash: "1234"
    },

    lmart: {
        username: "lmart",
        name: "Luis",
        passwordHash: "2345"
    }
}

module.exports = users // export users
```

Notice I changed the DB. You defined each user as an array, but that doesn' make sense and you weren't accessing them as arrays. Here each user is a single object.

Now to use it you can `require` it and it should work as expected:

```
const users = require('./my_db.js')  // the exported users becomes the `users`

const username = 'jdoe2'; 
const user = users[username]; 
console.log(user.name, user.passwordHash)
```